# Retrieve an object from collection by its name using nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

so Im currently making an application using MEAN stack. The problem i have at the moment is, when making a call to the API, I am able to successfully retrieve all objects and each object by ID from the database(using POSTMAN(Chrome)) I have set up using mongoose & express router. My question is, can I retrieve an object by it's name ? I have been searching the web and I am unsure how I could implement this. For example: This is the Api code i currently have.

```
    var Dishes = require('../../app/models/dishes');
    var Terms = require('../../app/models/terms');
    var config = require('../../config');

    module.exports = function(app,express){

    // api ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        var apiRouter = express.Router();

    // middleware to use for all requests
         apiRouter.use(function (req, res, next) {
            // do logging
            console.log('Somebody just came to our app!');
            next();
        });

    // Test routes to make sure everything is working
     //(accessed at GET http://localhost:3000/api)
        apiRouter.get('/', function (req, res) {
            res.json({message: 'Welcome to the API!'});
        });

        /** ================================= Dishes      ==========================================**/

    //on routes that end in /dishes , show all dishes in json
        apiRouter.get('/dishes', function (req, res) {

            Dishes.find(function (err, dishes) {

                // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing         after res.send(err) will execute
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                res.json(dishes); // return all dishes in JSON format

            });

        });

      //on routes that end in /dishes/:_id , show all the this with the   corresponding ID
    // get the dish with that id
    // (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api/dishes/:dish_id)
        apiRouter.get('/dishes/:_id',function(req, res) {

            Dishes.findById(req.params._id, function(err, dish) {
                if (err) res.send(err);

                // return that dish
               res.json(dish);

            });

        });

        return apiRouter;
    };
```

The dish model I am access is as follows:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

     //with Mongoose everything is derived from a schema ! Lets get a reference and define our Dishes Schema
     var DishSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        dishName: {type: String, index: {unique: true}},
        Desc : {type: String, index: { unique: true}},
        Allergy: String,
        HealthRisks: String
      },{collection:'Dishes'});

    module.exports = DishSchema;

     //The Next step is to compile our schema into a model
     var Dishes = mongoose.model('Dishes', DishSchema);//Dish Schema into model
    // return the model
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Dishes', DishSchema)
```

What I wish to do is make an api call to (/dishes/:dishName) and return the relevant dish. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apiRouter.get('/dishes/getByName/:dishName',function(req, res) {
    Dishes.findOne({dishName:req.params.dishName}, function(err, dish) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        // return that dish
       res.send(dish);
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately i have tried this before and on query of url "http://localhost:3000/api/dishes/Eggs Benedict " , this is what is returned:       'code' {
          "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"Eggs Benedict\" at     path \"_id\"",
          "name": "CastError",
          "kind": "ObjectId",
          "value": "Eggs Benedict",
           "path": "_id"
        }

Comment: Same result , it seems to refer to the path still being linked to _id of object.  ""message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"Eggs Benedict\" at path \"_id\""  ?

Comment: actually here the request is hitting the apiRouter.get('/dishes/:_id) and in that handler you are trying to find it by id Dishes.findById(req.params._id) and whcih is trying to convert the value Eggs to an id and throwing Cast error

Comment: what you can do here you can twick your api which i have edited

Comment: Worked like a charm !! Thanks very much :)